# Combining aggregations in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have objects of which some are grouped by a 'masterID'. I need an aggregation/query that shows me as result the object with the highest 'relevance' per object group by 'masterID'.

With aggregation of term 'masterID' I can get buckets for each 'masterID'. But how do I get the highest 'relevance' object within each bucket?

The queries so far are:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/pwo/_search?search_type=count&size=0&pretty=true' -d '{
  "aggregations": {
    "masterIDs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "masterID",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

and

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/pwo/_search?size=0&pretty=true' -d '{
  "aggregations": {
    "relevance": {
      "max": {
        "field": "relevance"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Is there a way to solve this with a single query?

Comment: Yes! you can add the `relevance` aggregation block in the `masterIDs` block

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. Any way to embed the field '_id' of the object with max 'relevance' to the output?

Comment: Seems to be working with a top_hits aggregation added to the relevance aggregation.

Comment: If problem is solved please answer your own question and accept it instead posting the answer in the question.

Comment: @eliasah , do you want to post the answer, I'll accept it then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the relevance aggregation block in the masterIDs block like following :

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/pwo/_search?size=0&pretty=true' -d '{
  "aggregations": {
    "masterIDs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "masterID",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "relevance": {
          "max": { "field" : "relevance" }
        },
        "aggregations": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```